# building a database for my site

Tags: database-design, normalization

I need help designing the database for my online custom suit store.  So far, i have created the tables for the products, orders, and my users/customers.  I think I need to add some tables to manage my shopping cart for customers while they are making their selections and customizing them.  At this point, i am a little confused on how to proceed.  does my shopping cart need to pretty much hold all the information that my orders tables will hold ultimately? as you can see from the attached image, orders have order items, and order items have order item options. this way, i can pull up each order item that a customer wants, and all of the customizations that go with each particular order.  Does this need to first done in my shopping cart, meaning that i would basically have to replicate all of the tables in the orders section of the database, or is there a better way?  Also, what else is my database application lacking in order to robustly run a website like www.indochino.com?

All help is appreciated...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `order` table to be a `shopping_cart` table, and remove all of the shipping address information from it.

Then create a separate `order` table that includes a `shopping_cart_id` that points to the associated shopping cart. This `order` table should include all of the necessary information for a posted order, like shipping address, line-item total amount, tax amount, order total amount, posted-date-time, etc.

I don't think a status field is the correct approach, because a shopping cart is not an order, and lots of order fields are not applicable to a shopping cart. These are fields that should not take a null value, because they are required for a completed order. Tables that store completely different things depending on a status field are a burden when it comes time to write reports on this data.

Comment: it's a matter of perspective.  one way to look at it is that a shopping cart represents  an order that hasn't been completed yet.  they are not completely different things.  they hold much of the same information.  it's really only the state of the order that is different.  and i think your assertion that the fields on order should not take a null value is misguided.  there's nothing wrong with having empty/null fields on the order table.  if you want to report on completed orders, it's really as simple as scoping the query to where status = 'complete' or whatever.

Comment: @Josh Deeden - Your approach either (1) complicates the creation of data integrity constraints or (2) avoids using appropriate data integrity constraints. I know there is a class of developers who do not see the value of DB constraints, but my experience has shown them to be extremely valuable in building bullit-proof systems. Minimizing "not applicable" nulls and magic-morphing tables are two ways that well-constrained systems may be designed.

Comment: I guess if you like duplication of code and data, then your approach is probably the right one.  However, if you favor DRYness and making things no more complicated than necessary, then I think my approach wins the day.  Minimizing non-applicable nulls at the expense of introducing duplication seems a little anal and rather impractical.

Comment: I guess the only other thing I'd suggest to the person who asked the question is look at how other, well-designed e-commerce solutions solve the problem.  Compare and contrast and find the solution that matches up with your own sensibilities.

Comment: Building constraints into the structure of the data rather than tacking them on to a structure that doesn't model the facts of the real world reduces, rather than expands, the complications. And although it may seem redundant, validating data all layer boundries in a system is a good practice that minimizes errors and creates a better separation of concerns.

Comment: This is the more flexible design especially if you want the user to be able to retain shopping cart items without turning them into an order rightnow like Amazon does. In spearate tables, I can put everything into the shopping cart and then pick only as much as I want to pay for right now for the actual order. but those other things can stay in may cart so I don't have to look for them the next time I go to order.

Comment: These are all very interesting perspectives, that i hadn't considered. I am learning much from these answers.  @josh, you said that Jeffrey's approach would cause data duplication, and I'm not sure where. could you explain. Also, you said to look at other e-commerce solutions, could you point me in the right direction. I have the diagram for os-commerce's solution, and it is anything but simple. I don't know if i'm understanding, but it looks like they duplicate a lot of data.  On that note, would i be better off just using some preexisting solutions and customizing it?

Comment: @jeffery so if i were to use your solution, my order table would look like this:  Orders -order_id **pk**, user_id **FK**, cart_id **FK**, address, city, state, zip, date_created

Comment: @Guided33 - My solution does not involve any duplication of data (which is the biggest sin one can commit in database design!). The code duplication occurs when integrity checks appear both in the business logic layer and in the database layer. This is not a very great problem, however, because the two layers manipulate the data in very different ways, so the checks will actually be very different. Database constraints are also important because the prevent errors from other sources besides the application, and because data errors in a live system are much harder to correct than programming...

Comment: (continued) errors, so multiple checks are worthwhile. Your table design looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a separate table for a shopping cart.  I would just use the existing order/order_item tables to hold the shopping cart information, and then add a status field on order that held values such as "incomplete", "complete", "shipped", etc.  Any orders that are incomplete are rendered as the shopping cart.  A state machine would be good candidate for managing the lifecycle of the order, IMHO.

Comment: great idea, if I were to do this, would i need to create a separate table for status values?

Comment: @Guided33 - With this kind of design the status field would typically be on the order table. Alternatively, a post_date of null could implicitly be used to indicate an incomplete order. (A shipping_date of null would signal an unfilled order, etc.) That would remove some of the redundancy inherient in this design.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you put an "in_cart bit" column on the order table? That way you can use the same tables but set in_cart to 1 where the order is not finalized yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shopping cart is a separate table, it should have orderid and userid as foreign keys.